# Retrieving row values from another file

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working in this project step by step. I can't understand why it is not copying the row string values from the "SheetName" used as argument being passed into this function(SheetName). The function can read a file and create a second file with checkboxes based on the number of column titles found in the first file, but the column titles are not being copied into the second file as captions for the checkboxes. Any help is appreciated.

```
 Function CallFunction(SheetName As Variant) As Long

 Dim text As String
 Dim titles(200) As String ' Dim titles(200) As String ' Array
 Dim nTitles As Integer
 Dim wks As Worksheet
 Dim myCaption As String
 Dim NewBook As Workbook

 PathName = Range("F22").Value
 Filename = Range("F23").Value

 ControlFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
 Workbooks.Open Filename:=PathName & "\" & Filename

 Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)

 For i = 1 To 199
     If Trim(wks.Cells(4, i).Value) = "" Then
        nTitles = i - 1
        Exit For
    End If
        titles(i - 1) = wks.Cells(4, i).Value
 Next

 i = 1

 Workbooks.Add
 Set NewBook = ActiveWorkbook
 NewBook.SaveAs fileExported
 Workbooks.Open (fileExported)

 For Each cell In Range(Sheets(SheetName).Cells(4, 1), Sheets(SheetName).Cells(4, 1 + nTitles))

    myCaption = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(4, i).Value

    With Sheets(SheetName).checkBoxes.Add(cell.Left, _
        cell.Top, cell.Width, cell.Height)
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 12
        .Caption = myCaption
        .Characters.text = myCaption
        .Border.Weight = xlThin
        .Name = myCaption
    End With

    i = i + 1
 Next
 End Function
```

Comment: Ok, I found the answer to my own question. Below is what I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question I just forgot to add the answer here. Ok, here it is

```
 ' Save all Jira column titles into jTitles
If sj = True Or ji = True Then
    For j = 1 To 199
         If Trim(wks1.Cells(4, j).Value) = "" Then
            titlesj = j - 1
            Exit For
        End If
            jTitles(j - 1) = wks1.Cells(4, j).Value
     Next

     j = 1

     ' Add column titles as checkboxes
     For j = 0 To titlesj
        Sheet1.ListBox1.AddItem jTitles(j)
        Sheet1.ListBox3.AddItem jTitles(j)
     Next
     wb1.Close
End If
```